# UITableViewCell not indenting when entering editing mode on iOS 13

Tags: uitableview, uikit, ios13

When entering editing mode the cells do not indent to allow for the delete icon. Rather the delete icon is displayed over the cells content.

[image: Screen Shot]

The `indentationWidth` is set to 10 in the nib file and `shouldIndentWhileEditing` is returning true.

This works fine on iOS 12 but not iOS 13 beta 8.

Comment: Hi there, did you find a solution to this issue? it happens the same for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 13 is more fussy when it comes to auto layout and nibs. Make sure that there isn't any changes to the Content View of the cell, e.g. some constraints or outlets.